# Streaming assets folder VS Resources Folder in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to Know the  difference between Streaming assets folder and resources folder in Unity3d?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity 3D: Asset Bundles vs. Resources folder vs www.Texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423126/unity-3d-asset-bundles-vs-resources-folder-vs-www-texture)

Answer (score 11):

Want to extend answer by holo559.

**Streaming Assets** are just copied as files and can thus be accessed as such. Useful for including files like sqlite databases or other files you want to be able to use [`StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.8) on. They do not work on some platforms such as WebGL due to the web not having filesystem support. Can also be interchanged during runtime.

**Resources** are embedded into your program and are therefore platform independent. Useful for having example text files for configurations such as json or yml files.

Answer (score 3):

**Streaming Assets** :
Any files placed in StreamingAssets are copied as it is to a particular folder on a target machine. Any asset placed inside StreamingAssets can be used while the application is running.

---

**Resources** :
Resources class allows you to find and access Objects including assets. You can access assets using "Resources.Load" stored in Resources. All assets in the "Resources" folders will be included in a build. This resources folder comes handy when we have to access multiple assets, instead of using their path names we can use its reference.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few more differences worth mentioning:

1- Unity will include the dependencies of an asset when you put it in a Resources folder, Streaming Assets won't.

2- Using Resource API you can both load an asset and deserialize it. using Streaming Assets you have to do all file operations manually.

3- Resource API allows you to Unload unused assets.

4- Unity will try to create a lookup tree when your game launches, depending on the number of assets, this can take time.